# Excluding positions to create new intervals in python

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a rope of length 0-5000. I want to divide this rope up so that the intervals in the lists shown bellow are cut out and the remainder is returned:

My lists:

```
['HE670029', '4095', '4096']
['HE670029', '4098', '4099']
['HE670029', '4102', '4102']
```

Desired output (does not have to be a list, can be written to file each `list` on a new line):

```
['HE670029', '0', '4094']
['HE670029', '4097', '4097']
['HE670029', '4100', '4101']
['HE670029', '4103', '5000']
```

I tried manipulating dictionaries, but without success. I don't know how to get this into a format that would allow me to perform the required operation.

Comment: Is your input guaranteed to be sorted? And can the intervals overlap?

Comment: The intervals cannot overlap (they are all distinct point/intervals along the rope), and most likely the input will be sorted, but it would be better if it did not have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ain't pretty, but it works:

```
sections_to_cut = [
        ['HE670029', '4095', '4096'],
        ['HE670029', '4098', '4099'],
        ['HE670029', '4102', '4102']
    ]

ropes = {}
for rope in sections_to_cut:
    if rope[0] not in ropes: # could use default dict instead
        ropes[rope[0]] = []
    ropes[rope[0]].append((int(rope[1]), int(rope[2])))

cut_ropes = []

for rope_name, exclude_values in ropes.items():
    sorted_ex = sorted(exclude_values, key=lambda x: x[0])
    a = 0
    for i in sorted_ex:
        cut_ropes.append([rope_name, str(a), str(i[0]-1)])
        a = i[1] + 1
    cut_ropes.append([rope_name, str(a), str(5000)])

print(cut_ropes)
# [['HE670029', '0', '4094'], ['HE670029', '4097', '4097'], ['HE670029', '4100', '4101'], ['HE670029', '4103', '5000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this before I saw that your intervals cannot overlap.  This approach is a bit of overkill, but I'll leave it up since it seems wasteful to throw it away.

*See bottom for short solution.*

OOP-ish way to do things:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left = int(left)
        self.right = int(right)
    def __contains__(self,x):
        return self.left <= int(x) <= self.right

intervals = [['HE670029', '4095', '4096'],
['HE670029', '4098', '4099'],
['HE670029', '4102', '4102']]

#if intervals aren't sorted, then do:
#cuts = [Interval(*x[1:]) for x in sorted(intervals,key=lambda i: i[1])]
cuts = [Interval(*x[1:]) for x in intervals]

#this step is overkill, since we know our intervals can't overlap
breakpoints = [x for x in range(1,5000) if any(x in cut for cut in cuts)]

def gen_segments(breakpoints, id_='HE670029', start=0, end=5000 ):
    for pair in chunks(breakpoints,2):
        if len(pair) < 2: #last breakpoint may be singleton
            pair += pair
        left,right = pair
        yield id_, start, left-1
        start = right+1
    yield id_, start, end
```

`chunks` being one of several chunk recipes like found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) page.  demo:

```
list(gen_segments(breakpoints))
Out[258]: 
[('HE670029', 0, 4094),
 ('HE670029', 4097, 4097),
 ('HE670029', 4100, 4101),
 ('HE670029', 4103, 5000)]
```

---

Like I said, the above is massively overkill.  If you know your intervals don't overlap, you don't need a fancy `Interval` class or anything.  Just do this:

```
breakpoints = [int(x) for interval in intervals for x in interval[1:]]
```

And then proceed directly with `gen_segments`, above.

Answer (score 0):

Ill not spoil it for you, but give you a hint. Given

```
xs = [
    ['HE670029', '4095', '4096'],
    ['HE670029', '4098', '4099'],
    ['HE670029', '4102', '4102']]
```

The first and the last sections are easy to do. Just 0->the first node, and then the last one is to 5000. You need the interim values ...

First create functions that can extract the two end values of your rope:

```
def head(x): return int(x[1])
def last(x): return int(x[-1])
```

Now you will need to segrigate each subsequent line like so:

```
[a,b for a,b in zip(xs[:-1], xs[1:])]
```

Now since you have these values, you can go ahead and use the functions which you just created to exract the last and first values of each ...

```
[(last(a),head(b)) for (a,b) in zip(xs[:-1], xs[1:])]
```

These are not the values that you want is it? You need to shift a little here ...

```
[(last(a)+1,head(b)-1) for (a,b) in zip(xs[:-1], xs[1:])]
```

Finally, just put the right list in:

```
xM = [['HE670029', str(last(a)+1),str(head(b)-1)] for (a,b) in zip(xs[:-1], xs[1:])]
```

Now you have 2 lists. `xs` and `xM`. I am sure you can loop through and combine them together ...Ypu can consideer playing with `zip`, `list` and `concat` if you want to improve the result.